# working with file&folder on server with c# application client side

Tags: c#

I want manage  multiple files and folders on server with c# code in clinet side

States such as create, delete, replace, search files,folder

I have Permition access to server (username,password) and connect with 
 NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: You can actually make use of FtpWebRequest class

Answer (score 0):

If your user doesn't have direct access to that server by UNC, you have to create a server side service that will communicate with your client software. Otherwise use [impersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka(v=vs.110).aspx) and regular System.IO classes with UNC paths. Of course, your user should have access rights to that folders.